# Add H2 database to Jetty with OSGI - cannot resolve driver

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, driver, datasource

I am using standalone Jetty for my webapp with the org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot bundle.
So far, everything worked out quite satisfying. But now I tried to use authentication and add a JDBS datasource in order to store my usercredentials.

To do so, I added the following code to my jetty.xml (according to the jetty documentation):

```
<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
<Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/admin</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
            <Set name="URL">jdbc:h2:C:\Users\Stephan\frontonics_data\admin</Set>
            <Set name="user">sa</Set>
            <Set name="password"></Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

I also created a properties file with the name of the driver (org.h2.Driver), the URL to the database, and so on.

Obviously, jetty seems to "understand" the link to the datasource and parses the properties file. But unfortunately, it cannot find the org.h2.Driver class, since it fires an exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver not found by  org.eclipse.jetty.security

In fact, I do not know why this dependency to org.h2.Driver cannot be resolved. I start the org.h2 bundle before the jetty bundle, I also tried adding org.h2 as imported package to the jetty bundle, but still get this error.

Does anybode know why jetty cannot resolve this dependency? Any hint?

[Edit] Stacktrace: (realm is my reference to the properties file, where also the driver class (org.h2.driver) is defined)

```
12:12:57.462 WARN  JDBCLoginService UserRealm jdbcrealm could not connect to database; will try later
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver not found by org.eclipse.jetty.security [41]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1550) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1988) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.connectDatabase(JDBCLoginService.java:198) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.loadUser(JDBCLoginService.java:239) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.MappedLoginService.login(MappedLoginService.java:221) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.login(JDBCLoginService.java:223) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:52) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.login(FormAuthenticator.java:192) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.validateRequest(FormAuthenticator.java:229) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:499) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1099) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:446) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:269) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.io_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
12:12:57.464 WARN  JDBCLoginService UserRealm jdbcrealm could not load user information from database
java.sql.SQLException: Can't connect to database
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.loadUser(JDBCLoginService.java:242) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.MappedLoginService.login(MappedLoginService.java:221) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.login(JDBCLoginService.java:223) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:52) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.login(FormAuthenticator.java:192) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.validateRequest(FormAuthenticator.java:229) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:499) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1099) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:446) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:269) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.io_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at  org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

Regards

Comment: could you please add a stacktrace?

Comment: i've added the stacktrace above

Answer (score 0):

Jetty boot uses the classloader of its bundle to resolve any classes from the configuration. To make Jetty see the packages of H2 I can think of one option:

Create a bundle that is the fragment of jetty-boot and imports the necessary package of H2. Your bundle will have only a MANIFEST.MF file with a content like the following:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: jettyboot.mix.with.h2
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot
Import-Package: org.h2,org.h2.jdbcx
```

**EDIT**

Based on the stacktrace, you use *JDBCLoginService*. I have just had a quick look and it uses *Class.forName(className)* in its code. I am sorry but it I am sure that this will not work for you.

I am not familiar with this part of Jetty but as much as I see, there is a *DataSourceLoginService*. That can use a pre-instantiated DataSource so classloading should not be a problem. That could work for you.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work either. I also tried to fiddle around with the host bundle's classpath... but no success. Do you see another option?

Comment: additional info: I extended the jetty boot bundle with a small bean that connects to the h2 database - this works. so, the jetty boot bundle itself seems to see the h2 packages. nevertheless, jetty itself (repsectively jetty.security) does not see the h2.driver class